# Using mySQL variables

Tags: mysql, variables

Is it possible in a sequence of SQL statements to get the value  of a field and use that to name a table in another statement? I'm not sure if that's clear, so here's an psudo-example of what I'm trying to do:

```
// dataType is equal to "ratings"
@var = select dataType from theTable where anID = 5;

// needs to run as "from ratings-table"
select field1,field2 from @var-table where anID = 5;
```

I've been reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html but either I don't properly understand this, or its not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: In your example, anID = 5 in both situations for the field1, field2 you would like to get.  Is this also true in your database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

```
SET @TableName := 'ratings';
SET @CreateQuery := CONCAT('SELECT `field1`, `field2` FROM `', @TableName, '-table` WHERE `anID` = 5');
PREPARE statementCreate FROM @CreateQuery;
EXECUTE statementCreate;
```